# Padrino rspec controller testing always green

Tags: ruby, rspec, sinatra, padrino

I am testing my controller with rspec on padrino with this code:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8d0df4c189e99c7cb7ea

If I run the test everythings goes fine and all the test will be green.
The problem is that those test must fail! The sign_in_admin on the before block doesn't allow the user to login and make the post call and also if I change the line

```
last_response.should_not be_ok
```

with

```
last_response.should be_ok
```

the test is always green.....
I don't know where I am wrong.

Here is my spec_helper.rb

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6442d02654cbee2cf3b5

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code is always passing is because your test is of the form:

```
lambda {}.should {}
```

which is equivalent to

```
lambda {}.should
```

since `should` ignores any block passed to it. That is further equivalent to:

```
lambda {}.should be_truthy
```

which always succeeds because `lambda {}` is a `Proc`, which is truthy.

You should only send `should` to a `Proc` if you want `should` to execute the proc for purposes of evaluating side effects (e.g. raising errors, interacting with other objects), for which there are matchers of the form `raise_error` and `change`. The same is true for passing a block to `expect`, which is the current syntax.

In your case, you can simply execute the code that in your current lambda expression and then check the value of `last_response`, as in:

```
it '...' do
  post ...
  last_response.should be_ok
end
```

or the more current:

```
it '...' do
  post ...
  expect(last_response).to be_ok
end
```